# concise review of Maxwell's electromagnetic equations for math students

Tags: reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics

I am a graduate student in applied mathematics and I am looking for a concise introduction to Maxwell's equations / basic principles of electromagnetism. (I have enjoyed the book by Purcell, Electricity and Magnetism, as an undergrad but I have forgotten most of it). I would like something that covers the conceptual details in a quick way and not necessarily a big textbook.

Thank you.

Comment: I highly recommend [A Student's Guide to Maxwell's Equations](http://www4.wittenberg.edu/maxwell/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738200565). You can easily find an e-version online. If you are interested you can try Jackson's book.

A quick googling should lead you to OCW website, t'hooft's [website](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html), etc. And you can find more extensive booklists.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: The t'hooft's website linked is soon removed, it seems. The new link: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~Gadda001/goodtheorist/index.html